# Update Phonegap project from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: cordova

How can I update an existing 3.0 project to the newest phonegap version 3.1? I saw the original cordova has a update command but couldn't found this command in the phonegap CLI.

Comment: You can find the platform guides [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides). They list how to upgrade your projects on every platform.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same problem. My solution was to install cordova as same as contained by phonegap.
Firstly, run `npm list -g` to confirm cordova version on phonegap.

```
└─┬ phonegap@3.1.0-0.15.0
  ├── colors@0.6.0-1
  ├─┬ cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0  <-- Pick this version
  │ ├─┬ elementtree@0.1.5
  │ │ └── sax@0.3.5
  │ ├─┬ express@3.0.0
```

Then you could install cordova for the version.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.1.0
```

You could use update command to your project. For example:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

It was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Cordova CLI Update

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

it's for linux

for windows without 'sudo'